# Using the MultiRowRangeFilter in Google Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I've been trying to use the MultiRowRangeFilter in Google Bigtable, but I didn't manage to make it work properly.
What I'm basically doing is scanning and processing different ranges from Bigtable using Dataflow.

```java
List<RowRange> ranges = getRanges();
MultiRowRangeFilter filter = new MultiRowRangeFilter(ranges);

Scan scan = new Scan();    
scan.setFilter(filter);

config = CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
                .withProjectId("my-project")
                .withInstanceId("my-instance")
                .withTableId("my-table")
                .withScan(scan)
                .build();

DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
options.setProject("my-project");
options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-bucket");
options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(Read.from(CloudBigtableIO.read(config)))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new MyFunction()))
                .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://output-bucket"));
```

`getRanges` is a function that returns a `List<RowRange>` that have been initialized like this:

```java
RowRange range = new RowRange("1388710#1823246", true, "1388710#1823302", true);
```

Instead of scanning and returning only the ranges that I'm interested in the scan returns all the data I have in my table.

Any idea what I've been doing wrong ?

Comment: Dataflow doesn't currently work well with MultiRowRangeFilter.  This bug has been open for a while, but we have not gotten to it yet: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1239

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't saw this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in the comments, MultiRowRangeFilter currently doesn't work with Cloud Dataflow, and the feature request is tracked in GitHub here:

https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1239